# Form controls resizing with OS settings

Tags: .net, vb.net

In short, I'm developing a level editor for a game, written in VB.NET, on .NET Fx 4.0. As a means of test, I deployed the application to a friend's laptop, which is configured to increase all form sizes to 125% (Windows Control Panel > Screen > Improve readability).

I noticed that his OS setting caused the forms in my application to be dramatically changed, in that controls are enlarged, pictureboxes don't fit and things even go off-screen.

To clarify, I combined two screenshots [that can be found here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59470454/aw-resize.png). The left side shows the 'normal' situation, and on the right everything is enlarged to 125%. As you can see, several buttons have gone off-screen, not to mention the fact that cursor calculations on the actual map area are now off by, surprise, 25%. Other dialog/modal forms are also affected. While I have not tested it, I assume that with a 150% setting, it would only get worse.

I am stumped as to how to resolve this issue. Should I try to resize my forms and seperators accordingly, programmatically, to accommodate the enlarged controls? How come other .NET programs such as paint.NET don't have the same problem?

**Edit 1**: From what I've gathered, the window resizing feature in Windows just upscales DPI. So that makes my question more specific: what is a good method to avoid having DPI changes irregularly displacing my form controls?

Comment: You should DOCK and/or ANCHOR all your controls to give the user the best experience. Even then there are still issues. I have heard some people say they use AUTOSCALEMODE (form property) set to DPI instead of FONT to help fix this.

Comment: @Steve I tried setting AutoScaleMode on one of the forms to DPI mode and rebuild the app, and that does seem to fix it. Although when I change back to 100% window size, the forms are too small once again. What confuses me is that if I rebuild the application for a second time, it works out alright. Which, in turn, leads me to guess that form sizes are related to some compile-time situation, even though that seems a bit silly...

Comment: Building on what Steve said, try using a FlowLayoutPanel which is anchored wrt the form boundaries.

Comment: Mika, as a developer, you must always use 100% DPI or else you will get that strange things you mentioned and more. If you are > 100, it does set the size of stuff based on your current DPI. This gets really bad when working with multiple developers and each has a different DPI!